# error accessing Kafka Cluster that is secured through SASL PLAINTEXT using KafkaTool

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl, apache-kafka-security

So I have secured a kafka cluster through below security mechanism in `server.properties` and added respective kafka and zookeeper `jaas.config` files

```
security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=PLAIN
```

and using below command to start the kafka tool

`kafkatool -J -Djava.security.auth.login.config=client_jaas.config`

where client_jaas.config consists of below content

```
sasl.mechanism=PLAIN
# Configure SASL_SSL if SSL encryption is enabled, otherwise configure SASL_PLAINTEXT
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT

sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required \
  username="admin" \
  password="password";
```

Kafkatool gets launched successfully cluster is being connected but when click on topic  to see list of all the topic it gives me below error

`Configured to use PLAINTTEXT but broker 0 does not support it.`

Below is the content of the `server_jaas.config` file

```
KafkaServer {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="password"
  user_admin="password";
};

Client {
  org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="admin"
  password="password";
};
```

Below are the listeners details in the `server.properties` file

```
listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
advertised.listeners=SASL_PLAINTEXT://:9092
```

If I see the full error log of kafaktool, of the output of command `kafkatool -J-Djava.security.auth.login.config=client_jaas.config`, below is what I see

```
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.436 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Starting application : Kafka Tool
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.437 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Version : 2.0.4
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.437 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Built : Feb 21, 2019
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.438 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - user.home : /home/vivek
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.438 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - user.dir : /opt/kafkatool2
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.438 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - os.name : Linux
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.438 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - java.runtime.version : 1.8.0_191-8u191-b12-2ubuntu0.18.04.1-b12
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.439 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - max memory=1305 MB
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.439 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - available processors=4
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.440 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - java.security.auth.login.config=client_jaas.config
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.443 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - java.security.auth.login.config exists = false
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.449 INFO  com.kafkatool.common.ExternalDecoderManager - Finding plugins in directory /opt/kafkatool2/plugins
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.449 INFO  com.kafkatool.common.ExternalDecoderManager - Found files in plugin directory, count=1
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.450 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Loading user settings
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.497 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Loading server group settings
01/Jun/2019 13:40:30.500 INFO  com.kafkatool.ui.MainApp - Loading server connection settings
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.854 INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread - Starting ZkClient event thread.
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.862 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.3.3-1203054, built on 11/17/2011 05:47 GMT
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.862 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:host.name=anakata
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.863 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_191
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.863 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.863 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.863 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.class.path=/opt/kafkatool2/.install4j/i4jruntime.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/glazedlists.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/gson-2.3.1.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/jgoodies-common-1.6.0.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/jgoodies-looks-2.5.3.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/jide-oss.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/jline.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/jopt-simple.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/kafka-clients.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/kafka.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/log4j.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/lz4.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/metrics-core.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/netty.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/ofjar.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/quaqua.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/scala-library.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/scala-parser-combinators.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/scala-xml.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/slf4j-api.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/slf4j-log4j12.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/snappy.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/zkclient.jar:/opt/kafkatool2/lib/zookeeper.jar
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.864 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.864 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.864 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.864 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.name=Linux
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.865 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.865 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:os.version=4.15.0-48-generic
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.865 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.name=vivek
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.866 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.home=/home/vivek
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.882 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Client environment:user.dir=/opt/kafkatool2
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.884 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=30000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@60b5eeff
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.917 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.927 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, initiating session
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.947 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x100097569c60010, negotiated timeout = 30000
01/Jun/2019 13:40:39.949 INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected)
01/Jun/2019 13:40:40.024 INFO  com.kafkatool.model.Broker - Parsing endpoint SASL_PLAINTEXT://anakata:9092
01/Jun/2019 13:40:40.025 INFO  com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper - Getting brokers from zookeeper, found 1
01/Jun/2019 13:40:40.025 INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread - Terminate ZkClient event thread.
01/Jun/2019 13:40:40.044 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x100097569c60010 closed
01/Jun/2019 13:40:40.044 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
01/Jun/2019 13:40:40.046 ERROR com.kafkatool.model.Broker - Configured to use PLAINTEXT but broker 0 does not support it. Configured types {SASL_PLAINTEXT=BrokerEndpoint{protocol='SASL_PLAINTEXT', host='anakata', port=9092}}
01/Jun/2019 13:40:40.048 ERROR com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper - Error getting topics
java.lang.Exception: Configured to use PLAINTEXT but broker 0 does not support it.
    at com.kafkatool.model.Broker.getSecurityTypeConnectString(Broker.java:169)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getProperties(KafkaMapper.java:258)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getNewConsumer(KafkaMapper.java:1100)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getNewConsumer(KafkaMapper.java:1095)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getNewConsumer(KafkaMapper.java:1085)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getTopics(KafkaMapper.java:420)
    at com.kafkatool.model.ServerConnection.getTopics(ServerConnection.java:221)
    at com.kafkatool.model.ServerConnection.hasTopic(ServerConnection.java:203)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.startPoller(KafkaMapper.java:105)
    at com.kafkatool.model.ServerConnection.connectInt(ServerConnection.java:336)
    at com.kafkatool.model.ServerConnection.connect(ServerConnection.java:315)
    at com.kafkatool.common.AsyncServerConnector.run(AsyncServerConnector.java:43)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
01/Jun/2019 13:40:40.052 ERROR com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper - Error starting consumer offset poller
java.lang.Exception: Configured to use PLAINTEXT but broker 0 does not support it.
    at com.kafkatool.model.Broker.getSecurityTypeConnectString(Broker.java:169)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getProperties(KafkaMapper.java:258)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getNewConsumer(KafkaMapper.java:1100)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getNewConsumer(KafkaMapper.java:1095)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getNewConsumer(KafkaMapper.java:1085)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.getTopics(KafkaMapper.java:420)
    at com.kafkatool.model.ServerConnection.getTopics(ServerConnection.java:221)
    at com.kafkatool.model.ServerConnection.hasTopic(ServerConnection.java:203)
    at com.kafkatool.model.KafkaMapper.startPoller(KafkaMapper.java:105)
    at com.kafkatool.model.ServerConnection.connectInt(ServerConnection.java:336)
    at com.kafkatool.model.ServerConnection.connect(ServerConnection.java:315)
    at com.kafkatool.common.AsyncServerConnector.run(AsyncServerConnector.java:43)
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error trace? Also, can you share the content of `server_jaas.config` ?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous added the logs and content of the config file.

Answer (score 2):

The comment line in your client_jaas.config does actually contain a clue on this:

> Configure SASL_SSL if SSL encryption is enabled, otherwise ***configure SASL_PLAINTEXT***

There seems to be a conflict in the 2 config settings you've provided.

In `server.properties`, you've mentioned:

`security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT`

whereas in your client_jaas.config, you've mentioned:

`security.protocol=SASL_SSL`

Try changing this to `SASL_PLAINTEXT`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: it didnt work even after changing the configuration to `SASL_PLAINTEXT`.

Comment: I've just noticed your latest edit to the post. Could you please share the listener and advertised listener details as well here? And I presume you would have restarted the brokers after making this change, right?

Comment: added the listeners details, and yes I restarted the broker after changing the configuration.